# How to return result from async play action

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework-2.0

I try to develope a simple REST-API with play Framework and i stuck on the following:

I have 2 Methods: Gets some database data

```
public CompletionStage<PagedList<Computer>> page(int page, int pageSize, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
    return supplyAsync(() -> {
        return ebeanServer.find(Computer.class).where()
                .ilike("name", "%" + filter + "%")
                .orderBy(sortBy + " " + order)
                .fetch("company")
                .setFirstRow(page * pageSize)
                .setMaxRows(pageSize)
                .findPagedList();
    } , executionContext);
}
```

And the second is: Returns the data

```
public CompletionStage<Result> list(int page, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
    // Run a db operation in another thread (using DatabaseExecutionContext)
    return computerRepository.page(page, 10, sortBy, order, filter).thenApplyAsync(list -> {
        // This is the HTTP rendering thread context
        return ok(views.html.list.render(list, sortBy, order, filter));
    }, httpExecutionContext.current());
}
```

Now i want to check some values before i return the Data to the Client: (Some header values for example)

```
public CompletionStage<Result> list(int page, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {

    If(x=„somedata“){
            // Run a db operation in another thread (using DatabaseExecutionContext)
            return computerRepository.page(page, 10, sortBy, order, filter).thenApplyAsync(list -> {
                // This is the HTTP rendering thread context
                return ok(views.html.list.render(list, sortBy, order, filter));
            }, httpExecutionContext.current());
    } Else {
       Return ok(„value is Not some Data ...“)
    }
}
```

The Problem is, that i cant return a simple result ... what is the best way to do this? Maybe warp the result also in a async method? Is this a good practice?

The example is form this github site: https://github.com/playframework/play-java-ebean-example

**Solution:**
With the awnser from Andriy Kuba i read the javadoc for CompletableFuture and CompletionStage again. It seams to be the right way to do this! For all who want to use Play framework in async (which is realy important) look at the example at https://github.com/playframework/play-java-ebean-example and read the javadoc for CompletionStage (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) and for CompletableFuture (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). With this in mind, it is very easy and a joy to write async code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the result in the `CompletionStage` just like

```
} Else {
   return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ok("value is Not some Data ..."))
}
```